# Как правильно использовать rel="nofollow"?

Tags: php, html

На wp-cms имею строки в contact.php:

```
< ?php if($facebook_url) { ?><li class="foot-facebook"><a href="<?php echo facebook_url; ?> ">Facebook</a></li><?php } ?>
```

В СSS (style.css):

```
.foot-twitter a { background:url(images/twitter.png) no-repeat; }
.foot-facebook a { background:url(images/facebook.png) no-repeat; }
```

Вопрос - как закрыть от индексации ссылку задаваемую через настройки темы, Куда и что воткнуть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="..." rel="noindex,nofollow">some text</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, только ссыль через php задана и такая постановка не работает

Comment: А какая разница? Будет так 

<a rel="noindex,nofollow" href="< ? php echo facebook_url; ? > ">Facebook</a></li>< ? php } ? >

Comment: Можно сделать так
< a onclick="location.href='< ? php echo facebook_url; ? >'">Facebook< / a >

Тогда надо добавить "cursor: pointer" в css

Comment: Я пробовал, ссылка индексируется по данным "посмотреть код страницы" и cy-pr. В местах где нет php работает. Думал может этот rel можно в css затолкать?

Comment: Rel и css - совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: Ссылка на fb всегда одинаковая?
Тогда можно так сделать
< a id="go_fb" >Facebook< / a >

А в js коде добавить:
$('#go_fb').click(function(){location.href='тут постоянная ссылка'});


Или так:
<script type="text/javascript">
function goFb(){
    location.href="< ? php echo facebook_url; ? >";
}
</script>
<a onclick="goFb(); return false;">Facebook</a>

Comment: щас с онкликом пробую

Comment: локейшан тоже не сработал, спасибо за скрипт, а то я их не умею)

Comment: А что, конструкцию <pre><code><noindex><nofollow><a href=""></a></nofollow></noindex></code></pre> отменили?